# PDO using MySql Case for ordering with bound variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been researching this and I think I've found the best solution but I'm not 100% sure. I have a good handle on PDO but this is the first time I've encountered CASE in mysql. This code is working but I'm wondering if it's efficient? If I were to have multiple keys, I would have to write many arrays to be able to search and order. Is there a shorter way to write this code or is this the most efficient? Thanks!

```
$filters = "
    AND (name LIKE :keys
    OR note LIKE :keys
    OR tagnum = :skeys)
";
$order = "
    ORDER BY
        CASE
            WHEN tagnum = :skeys THEN 0
            WHEN name = :skeys THEN 1
            WHEN name LIKE :lkeys THEN 2
            WHEN name LIKE :rkeys THEN 3
            ELSE 4
        END
    ASC
";
$arr[':keys'] = "%$keys%"; // both wild cards
$arr[':skeys'] = $keys; // stripped keys, no wild cards
$arr[':lkeys'] = "$keys%"; // left key, right wild card
$arr[':rkeys'] = "%$keys"; // right key, left wild card
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have complete control over how you order your resultset, then your solution is perfect. However, if you have multiple keys, then I would definitely consider using [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) because it will be faster and lot less comlicated to code. However, it has a different ranking algorithm than you have now.

Comment: Good info to have. Thank you.